# get return value from CFMODULE

Tags: coldfusion

I am using some vendor code that we have neither control over nor have the ability to view the source.

For the sake of explanation lets assume I have three files.

```
Test.cfm
VendorModule.cfm
Custom.cfm
```

In Test.cfm: I am calling the cfmodule as such:

```
<CFMODULE template="VendorModule.cfm">
```

I know nothing about the Vendor module; not the code it executes or the other modules it calls etc, EXCEPT that it will at some point call my file: Custom.cfm

In Custom.cfm: Does some logic and prints Yes or No. (Obviously the variable "something" gets defined in code I am omitting)

```
<cfif something is true>
    <cfoutput>Yes</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
    <cfoutput>No</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

When I run Test.cfm I get the Yes or No output as expected on the page.

What I want to do is have Custom.cfm set a variable that can then be read by Test.cfm.

So Custom.cfm would look like:

```
<cfif something is true>
    <cfset ??? = "Yes">
<cfelse>
    <cfset ??? = "No">
</cfif>
```

And Test.cfm would look like:

```
<CFMODULE template="VendorModule.cfm">
<!--- Do something here based on value of ??? set in Custom.cfm --->
```

Can this be done give what I have available to me?

Thanks!

Comment: If you need a return value, then a custom tag/module probably isn't the right construct for what you're trying to achieve. Sounds like you need a CFC function...

Comment: cfdump your variables scope before and after your cfmodule tag.  abort your page after the second dump.

Comment: what am I looking for in the variables scope?

Comment: You are looking for an indication of what happened in the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely not an ideal situation, but given the fact that you can't see the `vendormodule.cfm` code let alone change it, your choices are limited.

If `vendormodule.cfm` calls your `custom.cfm` in either a `cfinclude` or a `cfmodule` you could modify the scope you're after like this, it feels bad to even suggest it, but it should accomplish what you're after.

```
<cfif something is true>
  <cfset caller.caller.result = "Yes">
<cfelse>
  <cfset caller.caller.result = "No">
</cfif>
```

The above code would have to be modified depending at what level `custom.cfm` is called. For example, if `custom.cfm` was six levels deep, then it would reference the `variables` scope within `test.cfm` like this:

```
caller.caller.caller.caller.caller.caller.result
```

Your only other option would be to modify some other shared scope within `custom.cfm` that `test.cfm` can see.

Hope that helps.

Comment: for this to work, I would need to know how many levels deep my script is called correct? For example, if vendormodule calls another module, which calls another module which calls mine then the scope would be different correct? Also, how would I access this variable after the cfmodule call in test.cfm? What scope is it stored in?

Comment: For the example above, test.cfm would access the variable via `result`... and yes, you would have to know how many levels, *shudder*. not the best way to do it. if there was ANY chance you could change things to a cfc like steve suggested above, that's the way to go.

Comment: I can change how I call the their code, as long as it works the same without changing their code. I have complete control over the test.cfm file and custom.cfm files but that is it. Also, I tried setting `caller.caller.result` and then doing a `<cfdump var="#result">` in `test.cfm` but I just got an error saying result was not defined.

Comment: Adding this code to the top of 'custom.cfm' might help you debug exactly how `custom.cfm` is called from within their code. `<cfdump var="#variables#"> <cfabort>`

Comment: sure, doing that now. What am I looking for in this variable?

Comment: It's a structure that may show the hierarchy of how the different templates are called.

Comment: it would appear 6, so I'm trying `caller.caller.caller.caller.caller.caller.test = "some string"` and then dumping out the variables scope right after the cfmodule call. Does that sound right?

Comment: ugly doesn't begin to describe it. what would I have to get them to change to make this less ugly? Like what would be the best way for them to implement some sort of "shared" scope?

Comment: Changing it to a cfc that returns variable(s) seems more appropriate.

Comment: that seems unlikely to happen haha. anything else?

Comment: so I got my variable passed back, just wish there was a way I could do it that would not break if they changed their call stack

Answer (score 0):

Usually a cfmodule would return values by using the `Caller` scope, which is the caller of the cfmodule i.e. `Test.cfm`.  So maybe before and after you called the cfmodule, dump the `Variables` scope and see if there are any additional vars set by the cfmodule.

Some cfmodule may return vars in other scopes as well, e.g. `Request` scope.  So if you don't seen anything new set in `Variables` scope, try all other scopes.

Comment: I dumped out Variables and the value I set in custom.cfm was not there. I only dumped it out once because it is very large and takes a long time, but my value was not there. I can try request scope, but that it large too

Comment: Then use the caller scope as Henry has suggested

Comment: so if I set the variable in the caller scope in the custom.cfm what scope will it be in in the test.cfm?

Comment: Dump the keys and compare with structkeylist or structkeyarray

Comment: cfdump has lots of options.  You can use top/show/hide to limit the number of items returned, you can use a different output format or dump it to a file, etc.  the size of the struct being large shouldn't be more than a minor hindrance.  https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfdump